# display one 1st div and hide rest then after few seconds display 2nd div by hiding rest of them including 1st div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to display div 1 content by hiding rest of the div's and after few secs hide 1st and display 2nd div and after few seconds hide 2nd div and 1st div by displaying 3rd div in jquery.

In detail
if Div 1 is displaying hide 2nd and 3rd div and then display 2nd div after 5 secs by hiding div1 and div3
and then display 3rd div after 5secs by hiding div1 and div 2.

Hiding and showing of div should be after 5 secs.strong text

Answer (score 1):

To make your page wait for some seconds and after do somthing you need to do this below

```
    //create sleep function
    function sleep(delay) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
  //here you call the function with parameter the secods when you want to sleep you page. 1000 = 1s
  sleep(5000);
  //and here you alert an message after 5s
  alert("hello!");

    //here you can select the div and remove it or display it with js after the sleep 
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```